# ListView.setAdapter NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, listview

I was doing my homework for coursera course, when i catch NPE. Can't fix this problem for several days and can't continue without fixing. Google doesn't help.
**UPDATED CODE DOWN THE PAGE**
Here is my code:

MainActivity

```
List<Selfie> selfies = new ArrayList<Selfie>();
private CustomAdapter ADAPTER = new CustomAdapter(this, selfies);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    File youDir = new File("/sdcard/DailySelfie/");

    outer : for (File f : youDir.listFiles()) {
        //try to find selfie in files
        if (f.isFile()) {
            for (Selfie selfie : selfies) {
                if (selfie.getSelfieName() == f.getName()) {
                    continue outer;
                }
                else { continue;}
            }
            //code below works only if file doesn't exist in selfies.
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                 selfies.add(new Selfie(f.getName(), myBitmap));
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Selfie:

```
public class Selfie {
private Bitmap selfieBitmap;
private String selfieName;
public Selfie(String selfieName, Bitmap selfieBitmap) {
    this.selfieName = selfieName;
    this.selfieBitmap = selfieBitmap;
}
public String getSelfieName() {
    return selfieName;
}
public Bitmap getSelfieBitmap() {
    return selfieBitmap;
}
}
```

CustomAdapter:

```
private Context context;
private List<Selfie> selfies = new ArrayList<Selfie>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Selfie> selfies) {
    this.context = context;
    this.selfies = selfies;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return selfies.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return selfies.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Selfie selfie = selfies.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = new View(context);
        //get layout from row.xml
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(selfie.getSelfieBitmap());
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(selfie.getSelfieName());
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

ADB:

```
    04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-27 13:17:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Seems that I have a NPE at `lv.setAdapter(ADAPTER);`. Found same problems on StackOverflow, but no solution helped me. 
**UPDATE:** rewrote my code, so it's now

```
List<Selfie> selfies;
ListView lv;
private CustomAdapter ADAPTER;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    selfies =  new ArrayList<Selfie>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ADAPTER = new CustomAdapter(this, selfies);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
...
lv.setAdapter(ADAPTER);
}
```

still have same problem - NPE. I tried to move "lv =.. ; ADAPTER =..." to onResume, tried to put it to start of onResume - it doesn't help :(

Comment: Try moving everything in onResume() to onCreate()

Comment: tried both, don't help :(

Comment: Take a look at my answer below and update the `getCount()` method in your adapter accordingly. It may be because your `ArrayList` is either null or empty. Also, you should be able to set your adapter in `onCreate()`, so try it again there when testing my answer.

Comment: I've made an update to my answer that may help, this time focusing on your `getView()` method.

Comment: rewrote my code with yours and have NPE. Checked my List - it's not empty.

Comment: Found mistake...in my  getView() code i return convertView, but inflate to rowView. To make it work i need to return rowView. Thank everyone who helped and especially to PPartisan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the NPE relates to your `ListView`. Try to structure your app so that you declare class variables and initialise them in `onCreate()`. That way, you reference them later on (as you do in `onResume()`).

```
List<Selfie> selfies;
private CustomAdapter ADAPTER;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    selfies = new ArrayList<Selfie>();
    ADAPTER = new CustomAdapter(this, selfies);

    lv.setAdapter(ADAPTER);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /*
    *I don't quite see the purpose in this below section, 
    *as you can account for a null ArrayList in your adapter class
    */
    if (ADAPTER.getCount() >= 0) {
    lv.setAdapter(ADAPTER);
    }

}
```

Also, to explain the comment I made above a little better, you can account for null data in your adapter `getCount()` by treating null data as a `0` size list:

```
getCount() {
    if (selfies == null || selfies.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return selfies.size;
}
```

**Edit:** If the problem is confined to your adapter, then it may be an NPE coming from `getView()`. You can try the code below:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;
            Selfie selfie = selfies.get(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().
                        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            } else {
                rowView = convertView;
            }
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(selfie.getSelfieBitmap());
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(selfie.getSelfieName());

            return rowView;
        }
```

Comment: Tried this, still have NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
private CustomAdapter ADAPTER = new CustomAdapter(this, selfies);
```

into `onCreate` method because `this` context is use in class methods.i.e. rewrite as

```
 private CustomAdapter ADAPTER;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ADAPTER = new CustomAdapter(this, selfies);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this returns anything other than null:

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Could be that it cannot find the list.

Comment: checked, it returns listView.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);` in `onResume`, `setContentView` has not been called. `onResume` is always called before `onCreate`, so your `ListView` is not currently in the context. Hence the NullPointerException.

Change your Activity code to this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about the this you have setteded, when you initialazed the new Custom.... You have to initilizate it `onCreate()` ! (I mean for MainActivity class )

Comment: Initilizated it in onCreate - still NPE.

Answer (score 0):

your arraylist of selfies is empty because i see nothing added?
also your class Selfie only has getter but no setters, so how do u set a selfie to your arraylist of selfies then?

Comment: i removed code of setting selfies for easier reading. Added it, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that in my getView() code i returned convertView but inflated rowView. So convertView stays null. PPartisan showed me my mistake and gave worked code(below). To up the rating i must have 15 reputation, and i don't have. Could somebody, please, up his rating and his right answer?

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;
    Selfie selfie = selfies.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    } else {
        rowView = convertView;
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(selfie.getSelfieBitmap());
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(selfie.getSelfieName());

    return rowView;
}
```